# jquery load many links in one div?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, load

Have a  div `<div id="test"></div>`.
I load html (`test.php?nid=1`) into this div with jquery ajax().
In this loaded html i have another deep link. Example:

```
<div id="test">
<p>tttttt</p>
<a href="test.php?nid=2">aaa</a>
</div>
```

How can I load link `test.php?nid=2` in same `<div id="test">`?
And how   load link `test.php?nid=3` from `test.php?nid=2` in same `<div id="test">`?
Whats technigue?

Answer (score 1):

When your ajax request to your url succeed, use this to append the loaded data to your div.

```
$('#test').append(your_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to make this in a recursive way by binding the click event to the populated anchor and make it call a function like this :

```
function getLink(id){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php?nid=" + id,
        context: document.body,
        success: function(){
                   $('#test').apend("<a id ='" + i + "' >aaa</a>");
                   $('#test a').live("click", function(event){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        getLink($(this).attr('id') + 1);
                   });
        }
    });
}
```

So you first call the function with `id =1` like: `getLink(1)`, therfore it will append the first `a` to the div like `<a id="1">aaa</a>` from the url `test.php?nid=1` and bind it with `click` event that when it will be clicked call `getLink(2)` which in turn append the second a with `id = 2` from url `test.php?nid=2` and when it will be clicked call `getLink(3)` and so on...